# Using Date() to compare a date from 2017 causes error

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Getting 2 dates from the user, it works except: if both dates are in 2017, the error message displays when it obviously shouldn't.

I manually changed 2016 to 2017 to see if it made a difference, but didn't (using `Replace`).

Here is the validating code:

```
todays_date = Date()
todays_date = Replace(todays_date, "/", "-")

If m_date_01 < todays_date Or m_date_02 < todays_date Then
    m_valid   = False
    m_message = m_message & "<li>dates cannot be in the past</li>"
End If

response.write(todays_date)
response.write(m_date_01)
response.write(m_date_02)
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as VBScript and ASP.NET? Is it VB.NET? Is it classic ASP?

Comment: it is asp, I'm working with .asp files? is it the wrong tags? I assumed the default scripting language for asp is vb script?

Comment: right, i get it, shouldn't have tagged asp.net, apologies

Comment: Classic ASP uses VBScript, JScript, or PerlScript, and uses files with a .ASP extension. ASP.NET uses any .NET language, and the Web Forms framework within it uses files with .ASPX extension. Tagging your question appropriately ensures your question gets seen by the right people and that answers will be relevant to your environment.

Comment: The Replace will make todays_date a string and I suspect m_date_* are strings too. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28054351/603855 why you should use Date variables to work with dates.

Comment: What Ekkehard.Horner said. To be able to compare date strings directly you need them in a format that has the same sort order as the `Date` data (sub)type, e.g. the ISO date formats `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyymmdd`. Otherwise you must convert the strings to `Date` values before the comparison.

Comment: Actually we have no evidence from the presented code that the m_date_01 and m_date_02 vars are date-type or string-type. Therefore the code could work assuming the users are entering some form of string formatted same as the date after replacement of / with -. The problem is possibly with the user data format. Anyway - can you show us the results of the response.write() statements please ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat We *suspect* that they might be string values. Since this is ASP chances are pretty high that user-provided values come from some textfield. But I agree that the OP needs to provide more information about his input data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `<` and `>` to compare dates. Sometimes it'll work, but often it won't. Worse, it can look like it's working, in the sense that it doesn't give an error, but the results will be wrong. In your case, you're almost certainly getting the wrong result because your so-called dates are actually strings, and string comparison works quite differently than date comparison. (For example, if you sort "9-15-2016", "1-15-2017", and "12-15-2016" *as strings*, you'll get January, then December, then September.)

Instead, use `IsDate()` to make sure you're actually working with valid dates<sup>1</sup>, and then use `DateDiff("d", date1, date2)` to determine which date is later. If `date1` is larger (occurs later) than `date2`, the result will be less than 0. (You can use whatever interval you want, but `"d"` for "number of days" is probably the most useful.)

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is especially important if you're working with user input: even if we ignore the issue of malicious intent, people have, um, *interesting* ideas about how to write a date.</sub>